# displaying images in a .handlebars/html

Tags: html, express, handlebars.js

I'm trying to link images to my .handlebars/html files in my views directory. I've created a public folder as I discovered was necessary, but still can't get the linked images to appear when I open my web page.

Here is my node.js code...

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var request = require('request');

var app = express();
var handlebars = require('express-handlebars').create({defaultLayout: 'main'});
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(session({secret:'secretSauce'}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set('port', 3021);

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
res.render('index');
});

app.get('/setup', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('setup')
});

app.use(function(req,res){
  res.status(404);
  res.render('404');
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.type('plain/text');
  res.status(500);
  res.render('500');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express started on http://localhost:' + app.get('port') + '; press Ctrl-C to terminate.');
});
```

And this is a page I've tried to load images on:

```
<h1>
Getting a Mailjet Account, an API, and Misc. Set Up
</h1><br>
<p>
This first part is going to their website and signing up to get an account. The sign up page looks like this. You can click on the image to take you there.
</p>
<a href="https://app.mailjet.com/signup"><img src="/public/images/mailjet signup.jpg" alt="sign up page"></a>
<br>
<p>
Once you take care of business there, you can head to your account page and click on the link circled in the image below. That link will take you to where your private and public API keys are stored.
</p>
<img src="/public/images/mailjet APIKey.jpg" alt="account page">
<br>
<p>
Awesome, so the last major thing to think about is if you want to add a domain name to your account. Typically your emails that you use at sign up will be autamically set up as a sender, and it will make it look like emails are coming from that account. However, you may have multiple senders on a company domain. In that case you'll want to head over to the accuont settings and add that domain. This way in the future if employees send something it will automatically allow senders from the domain. This is really more of a logistical matter than     anything, and it doesn't directly affect using this How to Guide.
</p>
<ul>
  <li><a href="/">Prev</a> </li>
  <li><a href="">Next</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Should your img `src` have a space in it? e.g `<img src="/public/images/mailjet signup.jpg"`, should it not be something like `src="/public/images/mailjet/signup.jpg"` if it's located in the`/public/images/mailjet/` folder?

Comment: I think you're mistaking the name of the image for a file directory. The images are titled mailjet signup.jpg and mailjet APIKey.jpg. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Your Express code looks fine, try removing the spaces from the file names (it's generally bad practice to have spaces in file names). Does changing it to `/images/mailjet signup.jpg` work?

Comment: I took out the spaces and changed the directory path to no avail. Someone else in my class said that they were just uploading the images to google and using the links. So if all else fails I suppose I could do that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To get the images on the handlebars page or HTML we need to set the path on the index.js file or app.js file, it depends on you what is your starting page.

***Index.js***

```
app.use(express.static('views/images'));
```

`promotionapplication\views\images` - This is my folder structure, my index.js file is in `promotionapplication`, and i have kept my pics in the images folder. You can keep any of the structure of the folder but you should mention it in accordingly in `app.use`.

So now i can use any of the pics in the folder, by using the following code in handlebars page-

***first.handlebars***

```
 <img src="bckground.jpg" alt="piooop" />
```

Remember to reload the page after the changes made.

It works perfectly fine. If any questions please comment, i will try to give an answer.

Comment: Looking back at this I see the mistake in my code now. I have the public folder already registered with express to serve the static files, but I'm still prefixing the image path with /public. So I'm essentially looking for a directory called public inside the public directory express.js is using. Your answer is technically correct though.

Answer (score -1):

Use attachments in nodemailer options. LInk image src in your .hbs file to the unique cid in your attachment description like so:

```
src="cid:unique@unique" 

 const mailOptions = {
from: 'xxxxx',
to: x,
subject: `xxxx`,
template : 'xxx',
attachments: [
  {
    filename: 'xx.png',
    path: __dirname +'/images/xx.png',
    cid: 'unique@unique'
  },]
```

Comment: How is this related to my original question?